# ASC parameter when using TOPN function in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I've got this data:

[image]

Then have this measure:

```
amount = SUM( play[amount] )
```

Then I've tried to use the `ASC/DESC` arguments of the `TOPN` function in these two measures:

```
Top 2 customer per category ASC = 
VAR rnk = VALUES( play[customer] )

RETURN
CALCULATE(
    [amount],
    TOPN(
        2,
        ALL( play[customer] ),
        [amount],
        ASC
    ),
    RNK
)

Top 2 customer per category DESC = 
VAR rnk = VALUES( play[customer] )

RETURN
CALCULATE(
    [amount],
    TOPN(
        2,
        ALL( play[customer] ),
        [amount],
        DESC
    ),
    RNK
)
```

Now if I use these two measures it looks like the following:

[image]

What is going on?
Why is the measure `Top 2 customer per category ASC` showing nothing?
How do I amend that measure so that it shows values for the bottom two values of each category?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the second argument of `TOPN` should be a table, not an unfiltered column.

Regardless of what the `category` is, `ALL(play[customer])` returns the table:

```
customer
--------
xx
yy
zz
jj
qq
ff
```

The measure `[amount]` is still evaluated within the `category` filter context though so for `category = "a"` you get

```
customer  [amount]
------------------
xx          10
yy          12
zz          13
jj
qq
ff
```

and for `category = "b"` you get

```
customer  [amount]
------------------
xx
yy
zz
jj          15
qq          16
ff           9
```

These blanks are considered smaller than any number so they are what gets selected when you sort `ASC`.

Try this slightly modified measure instead:

```
Top 2 customer per category ASC =
VAR rnk = VALUES ( play[customer] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        [amount],
        TOPN ( 2, CALCULATETABLE ( play, ALL ( play[customer] ) ), [amount], ASC ),
        RNK
    )
```

Using `CALCULATETABLE`, the `category` filter context gets preserved.

---

P.S. To generate the tables above you can write a new calculated table like this:

```
Top2Table =
CALCULATETABLE (
    ADDCOLUMNS ( ALL ( play[customer] ), "amount", [amount] ),
    play[category] = "a" <or "b">
)
```

Comment: Thanks Alexis - took a couple of passes of your explanation to sink in but now I see it, and it is very clear. Thank you.